# sort row by column , when getting text always wrong

Tags: qt, sorting

I'm trying to get text and data from column in index number `0` from row that is selected
but I never get the right data I'm using simple model view `TreeView` with `QSortFilterProxyModel` proxy to sort the columns and `QStandardItemModel` as the model

This is the slot function that is triggered on each doubleClicked

```
connect(ui.treeView_mainwindow, SIGNAL(doubleClicked( const QModelIndex &)), this,SLOT(tree_itemClicked( const QModelIndex &))); 
....
...
void MainWindowContainer::tree_itemClicked(const QModelIndex & index)
{
    int iSelectedRow = index.row();
    QString groupID;
    QString groupName;
    groupID = m_model->item(iSelectedRow,0)->data(Qt::UserRole).toString();
    groupName = m_model->item(iSelectedRow,0)->text();      

 }
```

**UPDATE**:
Well, I found the answer but I have another question, the answer is :

```
QString groupID = index.model()->index(index.row(), 0, index.parent()).data(Qt::UserRole).toString();
    QString groupName = index.model()->index(index.row(), 0, index.parent()).data(Qt::DataRole).toString();
}
```

My other question is how do I set data to column in index ( for example: 3 ) in the selected row?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here most likely is that index.row() points to the row in the proxy model *after sorting*. This is most likely not the same row in your unsorted source model.

Try the following instead:

```
groupID = m_proxy_model->index(iSelectedRow,0).data(Qt::UserRole).toString();
```

Comment: But when i try to get the text from the column im getting error
error C2039: 'text' : is not a member of 'QModelIndex' .
how can i get the column text in index 0 in the row?

Comment: my guess is "groupName = m_proxy_model->index(iSelectedRow,0).data().toString();" should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
QStandardItem * QStandardItemModel::itemFromIndex ( const QModelIndex & index ) const;
```

Perhaps your rows are not set properly.
If this does not help, you should give an example tree, indicate what you click, what you expect, what you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
QModelIndex modelIndex = m_proxy_model->index(iSelectedRow,0);
m_proxy_model->data (modelIndex ,Qt::UserRole).toString();
```

Comment: how can i access the colum in index 0 in this selected row 
the text method does not work here .